# Layout is not getting data to data binding from view model

Tags: android-fragments, kotlin, android-databinding, kotlin-coroutines, android-viewmodel

I'm trying to learn how to use modelViewScope and liveData to fetch from a suspended db call and use the gathered data to data bind the view from fragment to eliminate the boilerplate code of setting up the view. I'm not getting any errors from my code but I don't get the value that I set in my view.

The TextView text will display @{viewModel.listingDetails.locationAddress instead of the LiveData info.

What am I missing? or What should I edit to get the proper value?

My Listing Repository Code:

```
interface ListingRepository {
    ...
    suspend fun getListingDetailsById(id: String): ListingDetailEntries
}
```

My Fragment Code:

```
class ListingDetailsFragment : ScopedFragment(), KodeinAware {
    override val kodein by closestKodein()
    private val viewModelFactoryInstanceFactory: ((String) -> ListingDetailsViewModelFactory) by factory()
    private lateinit var viewModel: ListingDetailsViewModel
    private val args: ListingDetailsFragmentArgs by navArgs()

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        viewModel = ViewModelProvider(this, viewModelFactoryInstanceFactory(args.id))
            .get(ListingDetailsViewModel::class.java)

        val binding: ListingDetailsFragmentBinding =
            DataBindingUtil.inflate(inflater, R.layout.listing_details_fragment, container, false)
        binding.lifecycleOwner = this
        binding.viewModel = viewModel
        return binding.root
    }
```

My ViewModel Code:

```
class ListingDetailsViewModel(
    private val id: String,
    private val listingRepository: ListingRepository
) : ViewModel() {
    var listingDetails = liveData(Dispatchers.IO) {
        val listing = listingRepository.getListingDetailsById(id)
        emit(listing)
    }
}
```

My Layout Code:

```
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <data>
        <variable
            name="viewModel"
            type="com.example.testsentia.ui.detail.ListingDetailsViewModel" />
    </data>

            <TextView
                ...
                android:text="@{viewModel.listingDetails.locationAddress" />
</layout>
```

I get the values I need when I observe from Fragment so I know that the data is present I just don't know how to do this properly.

Comment: `What am I missing?` -- the closing brace.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<TextView
...
android:text="@{viewModel.listingDetails.locationAddress" /> //You're missing closing brace here
```

Comment: Yes, that and adding String.valueOf

Thank you!